# Module not found in blender python file

Tags: python, blender

[Please help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbHJq.png)

please help me resolve this. I don't know how to import cv2 in the python command
I'm using blender 2.80

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: `python -m pip install opencv`

Comment: It doesn't work even after trying this